# Where does RN CellRendererComponent get its props from?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-props, react-native-flatlist, cellrenderer

In React Native, when `CellRendererComponent` is used in a `FlatList`, where does it get its `props` from? For example, if I want to set `style` to something specific, how is it done?

```
const CellRendererComponent = ({ item, index, onLayout, children, style } ) => {
    
}

<FlatList
   ...
  renderItem={renderItem}
  CellRendererComponent={CellRendererComponent}
   ...
/>
```

Looking at the definition of CellRendererProps, it appears `style` should be a prop in its own right, just as well as `item`.

```
export interface CellRendererProps<ItemT> {
  cellKey: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  index: number;
  item: ItemT;
  onFocusCapture?: ((event: FocusEvent) => void) | undefined;
  onLayout?: ((event: LayoutChangeEvent) => void) | undefined;
  style: StyleProp<ViewStyle> | undefined;
}
```

- See [CellRendererProps definition](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/95d09d32fee484cee3b75d1ae67f050302e84065/packages/virtualized-lists/Lists/VirtualizedList.d.ts#L90)
- [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/UeNoa2IWI) for testing